# Why is my bootstrap row overspilling it's container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Can any one explain why the bootstrap row below is overspilling it's container.

```
                   <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                            <div>Text</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                            <div class="pull-right">More Text
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.row` has `margin-left: -15px; margin-right: -15px;`. You should use it inside `.container` or `.container-fluid`.

See [bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) explaining the grid system.